# Using Swift Task inside a flatmap for async/await

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I'm trying to receive an `async` function return value inside a `flatMap` and wrap it under a `Task` to allow for async functionality but I'm having this error when I'm trying to access the `Task` value:

> 'async' property access in a function that does not support concurrency

How do I go about returning the value?

*Playground*

```swift
import UIKit

public func isEvenNumber(num:(Int)) async -> Result<Int, Error> {
    if num%2 == 0 {
        print("EVEN")
        return .success(1)
    }
    print("ODD")
    return .success(0)
}

func profileAsyncFunc() async -> Result<Bool, Error> {
    return await isEvenNumber(num: 3)
        .flatMap{ _ -> Result<Bool,Error> in
            
            Task {
                return await testAsyncFunc()
            }.value
         }
}

func testAsyncFunc() async -> Result<Bool, Error> {
    let basicTask = Task { () -> Result<Bool, Error> in
        .success(true)
    }
    return await basicTask.value
}

Task {
    await profileAsyncFunc()
}
```

Comment: What do you intend the term `.flatMap` to do here? This is not Combine, it's async/await. — Also, an async function should not return a Result; it sould return a value (Bool, or Int, in your case) or else throw. It looks as if you've partly converted the pieces of a Combine pipeline to async/await but you have not finished the conversion. — Finally, it's very difficult to understand what you are aiming at, since you are not doing anything that actually _is_ asynchronous. So why use async/await at all?

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

1. Swift concurrency simplifies this quite a bit. No `flatMap` is needed.
2. The `isEvenNumber` is not really asynchronous unless you `await` something. Adding `async` qualifier does not make it asynchronous. It only means that you could add some asynchronous code in the function, but only if you `await` something within the function.
3. In Swift concurrency, the `Result` type is no longer needed and quickly becomes syntactic noise. In an `async` function, you simply either `return` a value, or `throw` an error.

---

Let us assume that `isEvenNumber` is just a placeholder for something sufficiently complicated that you did need to make it asynchronous to avoid blocking the current actor. Furthermore, while you do not throw errors, let us assume that this is a proxy for some method that would.

If all of that were the case, you would need to make sure that you get it off the current actor with a `detached` task, and then it would be asynchronous, as you would `await` its `value`. And I am arbitrarily defining `isEven` to throw an error if the value is negative. (Clearly, this is not a reasonable reason to throw an error, but included it for illustrative purposes.)

Thus:

```swift
enum NumberError: Error {
    case negative
}

// This is not sufficiently computationally intensive to warrant making it run
// asynchronously, but let us assume that it was. You would do something like:

func isEven(_ num: Int) async throws -> Bool {
    if num < 0 { throw NumberError.negative }

    return await Task.detached {
        num.isMultiple(of: 2)
    }.value
}

func profileAsyncFunc() async throws -> Bool {
    try await isEven(3)
}
```

Then you could do:

```swift
Task {
    let isEven = try await profileAsyncFunc()
    print(isEven)
}
```

---

You said:

> I'm trying to receive an `async` function return value inside a `flatMap` …

Why? You do not need `flatMap` in Swift concurrency, as you might use in Combine.

If you are simply trying to adopt `async`-`await`, you can just excise this from your code. If there is some other problem that you are trying to solve by introducing `flatMap`, please edit the question providing a more complete example, and explain the intended rationale for `flatMap`.

As it stands, the example is sufficiently oversimplified that it makes it hard for us to understand the problem you are really trying to solve.